# Google Play Service Library is not listing in SDK Manager

Tags: android, google-play-services

Hello I want to use `google play service` in the android project. Right now I don't have it in my system so I am trying to install it using SDK manager but it's not listing `Google Play Service`. I am not sure if I am missing anything in this.

Please help & thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply updated my SDK Tools & SDK Platform-tools & restart the SDK manager then it is listing all options. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a lot of packages there including the latest SDKs (Wear/L API 20).

Make sure you have all sources selected in Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites the try reloading packages.

Comment: I am using android studio. I didn't find Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites